# XUnit compatibility with VS 2012 - Pro edition

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xunit.net

I am trying to implement xunit for test cases in my project and using VS 2012 Professional account.

The test case generation is done fine, but while running them, VS is unable to find any test case.

Tried running the test cases from VS inbuilt test option and using resharper's test option.

Please let me know, if some change in my approach is needed.

Comment: What does 'account' refer to ? Visual Studoi online? Are you effectively asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844614/cannot-run-xunit-with-visual-studio-2013-community#comment44104975_27844614 ?

Comment: By pro account I meant the Visual Studio 2012 pro edition( just wanted to check if xunit is working other versions and not this).
Yes I meant the same as mentioned by you in the given link.

Comment: OK then I'd prob close this question. Exec summary is 2012 pro edition should be able to run xunit tests via built in runner but there is stuff to get right as documented in the other answers