# Resharper 7.1 does not recognize xUnit tests

Tags: xunit.net, resharper-7.1

I finally got Resharper to recognize the xUnit plugin as installed, but it still does not see the test in my test project.  There is very little written about xUnit.  What can I do to troubleshoot this problem and get my testing started?

Comment: Does it still not recognize it after a rebuild ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the xUnit Runner not finding my tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214684/why-is-the-xunit-runner-not-finding-my-tests)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that in the year and a half since you posted this question, you've closed and opened Visual Studio 2013. But with ReSharper 8, that's all I have had to do :) Hopefully it's the same with 7.1