# Using Test filter criteria to run only certain xunit tests

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, xunit

I'm trying to only run a certain subsection of xunit tests using the tfs Test Filter Criteria:

[image]

The problem is that this is not doing anything, it still runs every test regardless of it's name, what might I be missing here? Is there something else I need to be doing since I'm using Xunit? Or is there another method of excluding tests in the test unit step I can use.

Answer (score 1):

> **Test filter criteria:** Filters tests from within the test assembly files. For example, `“Owner=james&Priority=1”`. This option works the
>   same way as the console option `/TestCaseFilter` for **vstest.console.exe**
>   For more information, see
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

Please double check your property of FullyQualifiedName in your assembly files. I'm not sure if `/TestCaseFilter` is also support in xUnit. You could give a try with directly running the test [using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629647/no-xunit-tests-discovered-by-vstest-console-exe/27844550#27844550) (vstest.console.exe). If it's not work, then this should also not work in TFS build task.

Add a related link talk about test filter for your reference: [VSTS/TFS VISUAL STUDIO TEST TASK – FILTER CRITERIA](http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/11/vststfs-visual-studio-test-task-filter-criteria/)

Comment: Have find a link: [Test discovery order is meaningful when filtering tests to a specific trait with vstest.console /TestCaseFilter](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/610) seems it's support.