# VSTest.Console.exe ignores test with xunit BeforeAfterTestAttribute

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net, testdriven.net, vstest

When running tests on our build server a test with an extra attribute gets ignored by the test runner.
This is the test:

```
[Fact]
[UseEmptyDatabase]
public void SutDoesWhatItNeedsToDo()
{
    // test logic
}
```

The custom attribute DROP CREATEs a local database.

Other information:

- Running the tests from the console picks up this test on my development server
- Running the tests from the console (and the TFS build) on the build server does *not* pick up this test
- Installing the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` nuget package *does nothing*
- Pointing the test runner to the bin folder with xunit test adapters (from the nuget package) *does nothing*
- On my dev server I have `TestDriven.NET` installed
- Adding an extra (dummy) test in this class with only a `[Fact]` attribute gets picked up on the build server (the class is public also)
- The `[UseEmptyDatabase]` should fail when running since it would not be able to actually restore a database (but it doesn't get that far)

Does anyone have any idea where to look next? I want to avoid re-writing the attribute setup to something within the scope of the test.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214684/why-is-the-xunit-runner-not-finding-my-tests/ but if the class is def public I'm out of ideas

Comment: @RubenBartelink It definitely is :), another regular `[Fact]` is being picked up

Comment: got any updates on this?

Comment: @Sander Nope, sorry mate.